# podfile gives an error on install or setup

Tags: ios, cocoapods

This is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'Mantle'
pod 'LBBlurredImage'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

After "pod install" or 'pod setup'I get the following errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem cocoapods (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/pod:18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall cocoapods

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem install cocoapods
```